# How to handle logging dependency in PlayFramework

Tags: playframework-2.0, slf4j

I'm having some issues with the internal logging inside PlayFramework.

I have a dependency which seem to be bringing `"org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"` which apparently clashes with Play's internal logging. In the current form, upon `compile` it gives me this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
    at play.api.libs.logback.LogbackLoggerConfigurator.configure(LogbackLoggerConfigurator.scala:80)
    at play.api.libs.logback.LogbackLoggerConfigurator.init(LogbackLoggerConfigurator.scala:26)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:94)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:65)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:64)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala:54)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:234)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:74)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.play$sbt$run$PlayRun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:74)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:100)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:53)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
```

But then excluding it makes it compile:

```
    projectDependencies := {
      Seq((projectID in root).value.exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"))
    }
```

But gives runtime exception:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:193)
    at edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.core.utilities.SerializationHelper.deserializeTextAnnotationFromBytes(SerializationHelper.java:124)
    at edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.pipeline.server.ServerClientAnnotator.annotate(ServerClientAnnotator.java:114)
    at org.allenai.ari.solvers.textilp.solvers.TextILPSolver.solve(TextILPSolver.scala:195)
    at controllers.SolveQuestion$$anonfun$solve$1.apply(SolveQuestion.scala:134)
    at controllers.SolveQuestion$$anonfun$solve$1.apply(SolveQuestion.scala:89)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Action.scala:371)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Action.scala:370)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:498)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter
```

because some of the internal components of my system use this logging. Any ideas how to fix this logging dependency nightmare?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, but it only happens when i'm trying to use coursier for dependency resolution. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude log4j dependency only from the conflicting package, not from the whole project.

Example:

```
libraryDependencies += "tf56" % "risk" % "1.0.3" exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
```

Comment: Shouldn't they have the same effect?